# How to remove the <br> tag in my HTML string using HtmlAgilityPack in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, html-agility-pack

I have an HTML string and I am using HtmlAgilityPack for parsing HTML string.

This is my html string:

```
<p class="Normal-P" style="direction: ltr; unicode-bidi: normal;"><span class="Normal-H">sample<br/></span> <span class="Normal-H">texting<br></span></p>
```

This HTML string has `<br>` tag in two places. How can I remove both of them?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) || [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's as easy as:

- loading the HTML fragment into an Agility Pack `HtmlDocument`
- getting all `<br />` tags using the `"//br"` xpath expression
- removing the tags obtained at the previous step using the `Remove()` method
- inspecting the result in the `DocumentNode.OuterHtml` property

Here it is in code:

```
const string htmlFragment =
    @"<p class=""Normal-P"" style=""direction: ltr; unicode-bidi: normal;"">" +
    @"<span class=""Normal-H"">sample<br/></span>" +
    @"<span class=""Normal-H"">texting<br></span></p> ";

var document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(htmlFragment);

foreach (var brTag in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//br"))
    brTag.Remove();

Console.WriteLine(document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string html = ...;
string html = Regex.Replace(html, "<br>", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: This does not handle the `<br/>` tag. And parsing HTML with Regex is generally a bad idea: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/390819

Comment: You can use <br.*?> to remove all kinds of <br>. This question is not about parsing=getting values, just about removing unnecessary parts of string and regex is a good solution for that.